# How to pass an array and a single element to a multiple argument method?

Tags: c#, methods

Example:

```
public void foo(params string[] s) { ... }
```

We can call this method with:

```
a) foo("test", "test2", "test3") // multiple single strings
b) foo(new string[]{"test", "test2", "test3"}) // string array
```

But it is not possible to call the method with:

```
c) foo("test", new string[]{"test", "test2", "test3"})
```

So when I have a single string and an array of strings, do I have to put them into one array first to call the method? Or is there a nice workaround to tell the method to consider the string array as single strings?

Comment: You have to put them into one array first

Comment: yes, you have to put them into one array...to match the function signature.  Unless you add a wrapper method that takes a string and an array of strings.

Comment: use Dictionary<string,string[]> for that

Answer (score 2):

While you can solve this without using an extension method, I actually recommend using this extension method as I find it very useful whenever I have a single object but need an IEnumerable<**T**> that simply returns that single object.

Extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableYieldExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            yield break;

        yield return item;
    }
}
```

The extension method is useful in many scenarios. In your case, you can now do this:

```
string[] someArray = new string[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
foo(someArray.Concat("test4".Yield()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're assuming that `string[] s` accepts a single string argument as well as an array of strings, which it does not.  You can achieve this via.

```
public static void Test(string[] array, params string[] s)
{

}
```

(Remember `params` has to be the last argument)

And then to invoke:

```
Test(new string[]{"test", "test2", "test3"}, "test");
```

Notice how the array is passed in first, and then the argument that is passed as `params`.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last parameter of a method can be a parameter array (`params`) so you can't pass more than one variable into a method whose signature only takes in `params`.

Therefore what you're trying to do in `C` isn't possible and you have to add that string into an array, or create an overload that also takes a string parameter first.

```
public void foo(string firstString, params string[] s)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your string to the array:

```
var newArray = new string[oldArray.length+1];
newArray[0]=yourString;
oldArray.CopyTo(newArray, 1);

foo(newArray);
```